# Split String by last number found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to split a string into 2 parts when the last number is found. Below are some examples.

1st example:

```
DECLARE @VAR1 VARCHAR(100) = 'AC-N-823 Germany, France'
SELECT RIGHT(@VAR1,CHARINDEX('[0-9]',REVERSE(@VAR1))-1)
```

My result should be:

```
1st part: AC-N-823
2nd part: Germany, France
```

2nd example:

```
DECLARE @VAR2 VARCHAR(100) = 'CR-21-Belgium-Canada'
SELECT RIGHT(@VAR2,CHARINDEX('[0-9]',REVERSE(@VAR2))-1)
```

My result should be:

```
1st part: CR-21
2nd part: Belgium-Canada
```

Comment: Do you have examples of strings with multiple numbers separated by non-digits?

Comment: no, there is only one number in the string. like my 2 examples

Comment: What happened to the '-' in the second example? What characters are not allowed as the beginning of the next element?

Comment: Look into "PATINDEX()" instead of "CHARINDEX()", it is much more appropriate here. Use the index it finds in your string by reversing it first, and then split at that point. I am leaving work or else I'd stick around to fully answer, but this should give you more than enough of a starting point.

Comment: @SeanLange i can add '-' to first part, no problem

Comment: "1st part" and "2nd part" - are these supposed to be output as columns or rows?

Comment: @haag1 Thanks you, the function you said was really useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @haag1 said, you should have a look at the PATINDEX function which allows for patterns. When omitting the character between both parts, both lengths (left and right) have to sum up to `LEN(@VAR)-1`, so this is probably what you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(@VAR, LEN(@VAR) + 1 - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@VAR))) AS FirstPart,
    RIGHT(@VAR, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(@VAR)) - 2) AS SecordPart
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.
certainly the PATINDEX function is very useful for my case.